# Using api call result as a parameter for CloudFormation resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

Is there anyway to make CloudFormation parameter dynamic? I know about the System Manager Parameter, but again I have to change its value manually. I want to use somehow the result of the API call or script(Bash, python) in my CloudFormation resources

for example, as part of the parameter, run a API call to get back some data (any data) and then use/reference the result into the resources, and all in one template.

Comment: No, obviously you cannot do that with a parameter directly. Either the code that deploys your cloudformation template needs to run the API call and pass the result to the parameter input or you need to create a custom resource within cloudformation itself which calls the api and uses the result.

Comment: What @luk2302 said - I would go with option 1 however as it'll just be easier.

Comment: @luk2302 can you show me an example, or any documentation regarding the first solution.

Comment: Main reason for my question is to receive all S3 buckets base on some criteria like if names starts with or include ... Then give this list as an option to resource so I can select one when I am deploying my stack.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cloudformation Custom resource to achieve similar effect, with some caveats.

As an example we can use AWS CDK, which provides a module to create custom resources, and even has a wrapper specifically designed to call AWS API and return the results: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_custom-resources.AwsSdkCall.html

Some things to remember:

1. Custom resource needs to return value in form `{'PhysicalResourceId': ..., Data: {"MyAttribute": ...}}` in order to support using `!GetAtt MyResource.MyAttribute` style of reference
2. Like any other CF resource, Custom resource is not triggered on every update, only if one of the parameters of the resource has changed. So if you supplied some parameter to your API call on stack creation, unless you change value, no update will happen and API call will not be triggered.